# PostgreSQL Stops After Starting following upgrade to Ubuntu 15.04 from 14.04

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ubuntu

I have a rails application that uses PostgreSQL.  Today is the first time messing around with it after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.04 from 14.04 (I upgraded just about a week ago).  When I try to start the rails server, it says:

```
"/home/nate/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.5/gems/activerecord-4.2.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize': could not connect to server: Connection refused (PG::ConnectionBad)
    Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?"
```

Based on this message, I first tried rebooting and then when that did not work, ran this command to start the server:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

I ran the rails server and it worked!  However, after clicking around a few times I got another similar message and noticed that the service had stopped again.  I started it again and then a few minutes later it happened again.

Next, I checked the PostgreSQL log and found this.  I see several "record with zero length at..." entries as well as "database system was interrupted" and "database was not properly shut down".  After some more searching I found some posts that said to use "pg_resetxlog", but with no real details on how to issue the command (it requires additional parameters)...but other sites say only do that as a very last resort.  So I'm not sure what to do.  Any ideas?  Here is the PostgreSQL log:

```
2015-05-14 14:46:40 CDT [12654-1] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2015-05-07 20:20:04 CDT
    2015-05-14 14:46:40 CDT [12655-1] [unknown]@[unknown] LOG:  incomplete startup packet
    2015-05-14 14:46:40 CDT [12659-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
    2015-05-14 14:46:40 CDT [12653-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
    2015-05-14 14:49:42 CDT [12871-1] LOG:  database system was interrupted; last known up at 2015-05-14 14:46:40 CDT
    2015-05-14 14:49:42 CDT [12871-2] LOG:  database system was not properly shut down; automatic recovery in progress
    2015-05-14 14:49:42 CDT [12871-3] LOG:  record with zero length at 0/147A88F8
    2015-05-14 14:49:42 CDT [12871-4] LOG:  redo is not required
    2015-05-14 14:49:42 CDT [12875-1] LOG:  autovacuum launcher started
    2015-05-14 14:49:42 CDT [12870-1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

Comment: What version of Postgres are you using? I have a feeling that 9.3 (The latest, I think), is not in the official repo.

Comment: The log file says it is ready. Did you try connecting from psql?

Comment: @Astor139 - I am using version 9.4.

Comment: @Jayadevan - When I run psql it says "psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused"

Comment: You could always use apt-get to reinstall postgres. It might be worth a go. If your running 9.4, then the repo is certainly up to date.

Comment: Try doing a ps and grep for postgres process (ps -eaf | grep postgres) . If it is running, find out on which prot it is running (ss -ap | grep postgres)

Comment: @Jayadevan - It isn't running until I run `sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql start` at which point it runs for a while and then stops.  While it is running, the output of `ss -ap | grep postgres` is `tcp    LISTEN     0      128          127.0.0.1:postgresql               *:*`

Comment: It runs for a while and then it stops? OK. Then check PostgreSQL log file and see why it is stopping.

Comment: @Jayadevan Thanks, LoL.  That is what I posted initially.  I ended up just re-installing Postgres and it is working now.

Answer (score 0):

1. Please edit this file **postgresql.conf** `listen_addresses = '*'`
2. Edit this file **pg_hba.conf** and add `host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5`

Comment: I followed your steps and after restarting the server, it is still doing the same thing.  It starts for about a minute and then stops again.